# Spring Security & CAS - Viewing secured page without login in

Tags: session, spring-security, cas

I have a webapp that uses Spring Security and SSO with CAS. There's also another webapp (in Classic ASP) that connect to CAS. And this situation happens sometimes:

Logged in to Java webapp and do stuff. 12 hours later (session has expired long ago) user goes to same page and it displays without redirecting to login page. This page has nocache for various web browsers so that should not be an issue.

If the user goes to the asp webapp. It asks for login so my guess is that cas had no ticket assigned for the user but how could he see the java web page?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the user closing his browser, and then returning back to the non-asp page, or leaving it open and simply switching tabs? I would try it with anything other than IE and see if you get the same case. IE has a known history of ignoring no-cache tags.

Comment: Sorry, this was so long ago (two jobs ago in fact) that I barely remember the issue.